# Add properties to ArrayList<Object> in Java

Tags: java, json, object

I have this class called Preferences. How can I push an object into this ArrayList?

```
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Preferences {
    public Preferences() {
        super();
    }

    ArrayList<Object> preferences;

    public void setPreferences(ArrayList<Object> preferences) {
        this.preferences= preferences;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getPreferences() {
        return preferences;
    }
}
```

In my main method I'm doing this:

```
package example;

public class Runner {
    public Runner() {
        super();

        Preferences preferences = new Preferences();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner runner = new Runner();
    }
}
```

I want to end up with an ArrayList of those object looking like this (the important bit is that I don't want to specify types because they can vary). I want preferenceValue to be reusable.

```
[
   {
       preferenceName: "Default Date",
       preferenceValue: "05/07/2020"
   },
   {
       preferenceName: "Default Number",
       preferenceValue: 55
   },
   {
       preferenceName: "goToHomePage",
       preferenceValue: true
   }
]
```

Comment: I would have a `Users` class which has a list of `User` where each user is just one person.

Comment: Your design is all wrong. You don't want a User which has a user which is a List of objects. You want a List of Users (i.e. a `<List<User>`), where each User is an object which has a userName (i.e. a field of type String, named `userName`).

Comment: There is no `add` method in your `User` class. Your code is not working..

Comment: The problem is I've done this because I don't want to specify type for the userName!

Comment: That makes no sense. What type other than String could a userName be? No user will ever be named `456` or `true`.

Comment: I have user userName as an example. Pretend it's not userName if that helps. It has to hold different types.

Comment: How about asking a question explaining clearly what you actually want to achieve, instead of letting us guess what it might be?

Comment: I have given an example of what I'm trying to achieve. You've all started to put String onto userName property... I've said "...the important bit is that I don't want to specify types because they can vary". I just need of help rather than discussion of why userName is going to hold other types than a String. Let's call it dynamicProperty then, not a userName...

Comment: Then type it as Object. But that will probably lead to many other problems: how will the code know what this object is? How will you prevent storing something that isn't serializable to JSON inside userName? How will you deserialize the JSON? If you told us what you want to achieve, at a higher level, we could provide actual help. And the fact that you don't yet grep basic stuff about classes, data structures and naming makes us think that your design is probably not the right one either. But since we don't know what you're trying to design...

Comment: how can the type of a username vary? A user's username will always be a string, surely? What else are you expecting it could possibly be? Do you mean the type of _user_ could vary (not the name)? That's fine but if you put something into a list of Object, then you lose any information about what type it was originally. So when you get it out again you need to know what type it was originally, and cast it to that type before you can use it meaningfully. Perhaps if you have different types of users you need some inheritance, or interface, or just a single type with some optional fields

Comment: Whatever it is, I agree with the earlier comments, this is a code smell which I suspect originates from a poorly designed data model

Comment: Say the Object holds in fact just a name and value for a preference. It can vary because { preferenceName: 'Default Date', preferenceValue: '05/07/2020' }, { preferenceName: 'Default Number', preferenceValue: 55 }, { preferenceName: 'goToHomepage', preferenceValue: true }. Can you see how preferenceValue can be reused in many scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to need

```
public class User {
    private final String userName;
    public User(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
}

public class Runner {
    final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public Runner() {
        users.add(new User("User 1"));
        users.add(new User("User 2"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner runner = new Runner();
    }
}
```

> It has to hold different types.

If you have User record but no idea what the attributes or their values might be you could use a Map.

```
public class User {
    private final Map<String, Object> attributes;
    public User(Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        this.attributes= attributes;
    }
    public User(String key, Object value, Object... keysAndValues) {
        this(new LinkedHashMap<>());
        attributes.put(key, value);
        for (int i = 0; i < keysAndValues.length; i += 2)
            attributes.put((String) keysAndValues[i], keysAndValues[i+1]);
    }

    public Map<String, Object>getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }
}

public class Runner {
    final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public Runner() {
        users.add(new User("userName", "User 1", "favouriteNumber", 7));
        users.add(new User("userName", "User 2", "colour", Color.BLUE));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner runner = new Runner();
    }
}
```

Here I am assuming your attribute names are String type. If you are using YAML for example, it can have any type as an attribute, so you could just use `Object`

```
{ preferenceName: 'Default Date', preferenceValue: '05/07/2020' }, 
{ preferenceName: 'Default Number', preferenceValue: 55 }, 
{ preferenceName: 'goToHomepage', preferenceValue: true }
```

I would structure this as

```
new User("Default Date", LocalDate.parse("05/07/2020", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")),
         "Default Number", 55,
         "goToHomepage", true);
```

However, you would ideally know what the possible attributes are in advance and use a User which looks like

```
class User {
    LocalDate defaultDate;
    long defaultNumber;
    boolean goToHomepage;
}
```

Comment: "...the important bit is that I don't want to specify types because they can vary". The way I want to use an arraylist of objects is not to define userName as String.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz true, but it's clear enough to show what would be a normal thing to do.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk are you saying you have no idea what attributes a User might have?

Comment: I am saying, userName might eventually hold types other than String, that's why I don't want to specify it.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk See my second example, which allows arbitrary attributes.  Any userName which is not a String, you could treat as a String.